# How can I Generate Card view at run time to display data from Sqlite?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-cardview

Hello I want a small help. I am working on a project to recommend colleges based on aggregate, category and Cities. I know how to display college list in Simple list view at runtime but I want to display it systematically using sub text views for displaying columns data so it will be user friendly to read the list of colleges.

Below is my code to display simple generated list of colleges.

**DisplayList.java**

```
package com.example.dsecollegerecommender;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import static java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean;

public class DisplayList extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        HashMap<String, String> cities = new HashMap<>();

        Boolean city1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Pune");
        Boolean city2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Amravati");
        Boolean city3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Ahmednagar");
        Boolean city4 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Nashik");
        Boolean city5 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Nanded");
        Boolean city6 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Aurangabad");
        Boolean city7 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Nagpur");
        Boolean city8 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Mumbai");
        Boolean city9 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Sangli");

        if(city1) {
            cities.put("city1", "Pune");
        }
        if(city2) {
            cities.put("city2", "Amravati");
        }
        if(city3) {
            cities.put("city3", "Ahmednagar");
        }
        if(city4) {
            cities.put("city4", "Nashik");
        }
        if(city5) {
            cities.put("city5", "Nanded");
        }
        if (city6) {
            cities.put("city6", "Aurangabad");
        }
        if(city7) {
            cities.put("city7", "Nagpur");
        }
        if(city8) {
            cities.put("city8", "Mumbai");
        }
        if(city9) {
            cities.put("city9", "Sangli");
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        List<String> colleges = databaseAccess.getColleges((String)bundle.get("Percentage"),(String)bundle.get("Category"), cities);
        databaseAccess.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, colleges);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**function getColleges() from DatabaseAccess.java returns the list of colleges**

```
public List<String> getColleges(String per, String cat, HashMap<String,String> cities) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String pune = cities.get("city1");
        String amra = cities.get("city2");
        String ahmed = cities.get("city3");
        String nashik = cities.get("city4");
        String nanded = cities.get("city5");
        String aurang = cities.get("city6");
        String nagpur = cities.get("city7");
        String mumbai = cities.get("city8");
        String sangli = cities.get("city9");
        String[] vals = new String[cities.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cities.entrySet()) {
            vals[index] = entry.getValue();
            index++;
        }
        if(pune == "Pune" || amra == "Amravati" || ahmed == "Ahmednagar" || nashik == "Nashik" || nanded == "Nanded" || aurang == "Aurangbad" || nagpur == "Nagpur" || mumbai == "Mumbai" || sangli == "Sangli") {
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Colleges WHERE ("+cat+" BETWEEN "+(Float.parseFloat(per)-5)+" AND " +(Float.parseFloat(per)+5)+") AND city IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ORDER BY "+cat+" DESC", vals);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                if(cat.equals("Open")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                }
                if(cat.equals("Obc")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(6));
                }
                if(cat.equals("Sc")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(7));
                }
                if(cat.equals("St")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(8));
                }
                if(cat.equals("Vjnt")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(9));
                }
                if(cat.equals("Ews")) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(10));
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I want to display Dte code, college name, location, percentage just like below image link.

**[LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFlC.png)**

Comment: Use recycler view : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom views for ListView items then you need to create custom adapter.

Here is an example:

```
public class BrandsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayNode _data_set;
    private Context _context;

    public BrandsListAdapter(ArrayNode dataSet, @NonNull Context context) {
        super();
        this._context = context;
        this._data_set = dataSet;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return _data_set.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {
            JsonNode list_model = _data_set.get(position);

            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layout_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
                convertView = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_brands, parent, false);
            }

            
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then in your code in activity where the list is you can do this:

```
BrandListAdapter adapter = new BrandListAdapter(dataset, getBaseContext());
```

In this adapter I used:

```
if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layout_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
            convertView = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_brands, parent, false);
        }
```

This way I inflated my custom layout named `item_brands`, which I earlier created in `res>layouts` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_layout_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_layout_margin">

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="@dimen/brand_image_width"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/brand_image_height"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
       android:id="@+id/brand_photo"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
            
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in `getView()` in `CustomAdapter` you can use this to get views and fill your data:

```
ImageView brand_image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.brand_photo);
```

And use `brand_image` or any other variable as usual. For you to get that CardView look you can use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:text="SOMETEXT"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle1"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:id="@+id/tv_brand_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:text="SOMETEXT"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle1"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
           />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:text="SOMETEXT"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle1"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

so you get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CardView with RecyclerView. For that you will have to create Model class, Adapter that will fetch data into cards.
Basically it will be a For loop that will fetch records from sqlite into desired textview on the card.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fetch data into Cards ?

Comment: @YashodeepD I can't help you with full code. But here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APZlsLTcX5g          I have done this exactly same for by school project. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: No for loop needed when you use the adapter as it should be used. In his question he already has data about colleges as I can see, now he only needs to fill views but he doesn't know how to do that. @YashodeepD I gave you my answer above. You can literally just copy it into your code and do some small changes to use it for your problem. You need ListAdapter or RecyclerView Adapter, depends on what you want to use. With that adapter, you'll pass data into your views.

Comment: @techfangirl Thanks that helped me Finally, I was trying from almost two days working on recycler view ,your recommend video helped me then.